# google play services library not working with ActionbarSherlock library

Tags: google-maps, actionbarsherlock, google-maps-android-api-2, android-library, google-play-services

I wanna use map v2 for my app. But while I use ActionbarSherlock library my google-play-services-lib library does not work.
If I delete ActionbarSherlock library then it work properly.
But need both of that library for my project.
Help me please!
Note: my apps's minSdkVersion="11" and targetSdkVersion="17"

Comment: Could you please explain deeper what is wrong? Some code, some error logs, ... Have you tried to use SupportMapFragment??

Comment: Some code you've tried so far will be helpful!

Comment: Did you make sure to remove the stand-alone supportv4 library, as ActionBarSherlock will include this library as a dependency?

Comment: @TwistedUmbrella, how can i remove that?

Comment: @AbuSalehMusa Verify that there is no a `android-support-v4.jar` in your project's libs folder. Also make sure that every `android-support-v4.jar` in all the libraries you access, such as ActionBarSherlock are the same file (can be accomplished by picking one and performing a copy and paste into the libs folder of all others that have one)